# .NET, Why must I use *Specified property to force serialization? Is there a way to not do this?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xml-serialization

I am using xml-serialization in my project to serialize and deserialize objects based on an xml schema.  I used the xsd tool to create classes to use when serializing / deserializing the objects.

When I go to serialize the object before sending, I am forced to set the *Specified property to true in order to force the serializer to serialize all propeties that are not of type `string`.

Is there a way to force the serialization of all properties without having to set the *Specified property to true?

Comment: Can you provide your class definition?

Comment: I cannot provide the entire class... too large to post here.  What would be best to troubleshoot with?

Comment: There is no other way to do this if you use XML Serialization. Can you use the Data Contract Serializer? Or maybe LINQ to XML?

Comment: It may be possible to go with the Data Contract Serializer but not LINQ.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: We have figured out that each item in the schema must be of type string in order to forgo setting the *specified property.  Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `FooSpecified` property is used to control whether the `Foo` property must be serialized. If you always want to serialize the property, just remove the `FooSpecified` property.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to use the code generated by the XSD tool for maintenance reasons moving forward.  Removing something from the generated class is not an option.

Comment: OK... can you change the XSD then? If you mark the property as not nullable, the FooSpecified property won't be generated

Comment: Unfortunately no, I cannot change the schema from the other end.  Thanks for the thought and suggestion.

Comment: An other option would be to re-generate the code using the XSD tool and specify the option to NOT generate 'specified' properties.

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt Xsd2Code tool has option to whether include Specified field or not

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but none of the other answers (except perhaps the suggestion of using Xsd2Code) really produces an ideal solution when you're generating code as part of your build and your .xsd may change several times during a single release cycle.

An easy way for me to get what I really wanted and still use xsd.exe was to run the generated file through a simple post-processor.  The code for the post-processor is as follows:

```
namespace XsdAutoSpecify
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Specify a file name");
            }

            string fileName = args[0];
            Regex regex = new Regex(".*private bool (?<fieldName>.*)Specified;");

            IList<string> result = new List<string>();
            IDictionary<string, string> edits = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
            {
                result.Add(line);
                if (line.Contains("public partial class"))
                {
                    // Don't pollute other classes which may contain like-named fields
                    edits.Clear();
                }
                else if (regex.IsMatch(line))
                {
                    // We found a "private bool fooSpecified;" line.  Add
                    // an entry to our edit dictionary.
                    string fieldName = regex.Match(line).Groups["fieldName"].Value;
                    string lineToAppend = string.Format("this.{0} = value;", fieldName);
                    string newLine = string.Format("                this.{0}Specified = true;", fieldName);
                    edits[lineToAppend] = newLine;
                }
                else if (edits.ContainsKey(line.Trim()))
                {
                    // Use our edit dictionary to add an autospecifier to the foo setter, as follows:
                    //   set {
                    //       this.fooField = value;
                    //       this.fooFieldSpecified = true;
                    //   }
                    result.Add(edits[line.Trim()]);
                }
            }

            // Overwrite the result
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The result is generated code similar to the following:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public barEnum foo {
        get {
            return this.fooField;
        }
        set {
            this.fooField = value;
            this.fooFieldSpecified = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a default value to your schema and then use the [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx).

For example, you could have the following in your schema:

```
<xs:element name="color" type="xs:string" default="red"/>
```

And then the following property for serialization:

```
[DefaultValue(red)]
public string color { get; set; }
```

This should force the color property to always serialize as "red" if it has not been explicitly set to something else.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?  What would this element of the schema look like?

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, though I do not know if we can do this from the other end where the schema is being created.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought you were creating the schema as well.  Regardless, you should still be able to use the DefaultValueAttribute in your serialization classes.  The trick is determining what the correct default value should be if it's not defined by the schema.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and ended up setting all *Specified properties to true by reflection.

Like

```
var customer = new Customer();
foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(Customer).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Specified")))
{
    propertyInfo.SetValue(customer, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We found that the answer to this question is to make sure that the schema elements are all defined as `string` data types.  This will make sure that the serializer serializes all fields without the use of the correlated *specified property.

Comment: This is really not the best answer. See Thomas L.'s above.

Comment: It has drawbacks, since you have to maintain the string constant in your C# instead of as an enumerator in your xsd, but it's a better option than Thomas L's in some cases.  Among other things, it doesn't require manual (or automated) editing of the generated code, and it keeps parameters from automatically being serialized as their default values.

Comment: Not an answer where the consumer has no control of the xsd.